# Conditional button based on a checkbox

Tags: infopath, sharepoint-online

I am building a form on infopath for SharePoint.
The condition is that only if checkbox is ticked then the person should be able to press submit button.

I have done conditional properties so familiar with them. Anyone know how to do for a check box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a Rule for the submit button, the rule type should be "Formatting", and the condition for the rule should be as below,

```
checkboxfield=FALSE
```

and under Formatting, select "Hide this control" or you can try selecting "Disable this control".

If you do the above, then when the InfoPath loads, the submit button will be hidden and then when selecting the check box the "Submit button" will be visible.

Comment: that worked but having and between rules didnt work.
    checkboxfield=FALSE and checkboxfield1=FALSE and checkboxfield=FALSE.

When i tick the first box, control becomes active. I need multiple checkbox's to be clicked before control is active. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can use rules to make sure all the check boxes do not show up when the form is opened.
Such that the first Check Box will enable the next one and the last checkbox enables the button.